# Inject dependencies into a custom solarium document

Tags: symfony, solarium

I'm using [NelmioSolariumBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSolariumBundle) in a [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) project to integrate [solarium](/questions/tagged/solarium).

My controller

```
$query = $this->client->createSelect(array(
    'documentclass' => 'MY\SolariumDocument'
));
```

In my custom `documentclass`, I have a field that store a reference of the category of the document retrived from [solr](/questions/tagged/solr). I need to replace that reference with the correspondent label.

That's why I thought of injecting `doctrine.orm.entity_manager` into my `documentclass`. 
I turned it into a service and through a setter I injected the entity manager but it didn't work `getRepository on non-object` which makes sense because that transformation is made in the constructor.

How do I transform attributes of my `documentclass` through `doctrine.orm.entity_manager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way is factor class which uses solr and the entity-manager.

1. get your document from solr
2. transform the fields you want

You can try the [solr-bundle](https://github.com/floriansemm/SolrBundle). It integrates solr-documents/indexing into doctrine.

Comment: Very interesting! However I need a solarium solution because of the huge legacy based on it

Comment: I don't know if there is a generic out-of-a-box solution